# How do I convert a reference cell to a string in Excel?

Tags: excel

I used the TRIM function on a column to remove the spaces at the start of each cell.

I want to delete the original column and have the new column without spaces at the beginning on its own. However, when clicking on the new column, each row will be TRIM(X2) for instance.

How can I convert this column of cell references to strings?

Comment: Hello EJMC, to mark your question as answered, you have to select one answer by clicking on the tick outline at the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your new column and then use Paste Special > Values over it. Then delete the first first column.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the trimmed data and paste special -> paste values